# How to import existing SQLite database to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got an existing SQLite database that I want to work with my Android application. I have looked at all the tutorials online, which are not working for me. I am getting an error when I launch the app in the emulator that says the table I have created in the database does not exist *(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: adk_peaks (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM adk_peaks WHERE 1)*.

adk_peaks is the name of the table. Right now I am only trying to get the information from the table to display in a TextView.

Below is my extension of SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
package kyle.peaktracker;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "peaks.db";
    //private static final String DATABASE_PATH =             "/app/src/main/assests/Database/";
    //private static final String DATABASE_PATH =     "/data/data/kyle.peaktracker/databases/";
    //private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\Database\\";
    public static String DATABASE_PATH = ""; //final?
    private static final String TABLE_ADK = "adk_peaks";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


    //Columns
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "_height";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIMBED = "_climbed";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE = "_date";
    private static final String COLUMN_LIST = "_list";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        DATABASE_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException
    {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist)
        {
            Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");

        }
        boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist1)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try
            {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    //Check database already exist or not
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try
        {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkDB = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
        }
        return checkDB;
    }


   private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
   {
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }

    public void db_delete()
    {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("delete database file.");
        }
    }

    //Open database
    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void closeDataBase()throws SQLException
    {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    //Override onCreate and onUpgrade
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        /*String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADK + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_HEIGHT + " INTEGER " +
                COLUMN_CLIMBED + " INTEGER " +
                COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_LIST + " TEXT " +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query); */
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ADK);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ADK + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_name"))!= null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_name"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        c.close(); //Added
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity:
    package kyle.peaktracker;

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView testText;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_text);
        //dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
        try {
            dbHandler.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {

            dbHandler.openDatabase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        testText.setText(dbString);
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Answer (score 0):

Change database path with fully qualified path like:
path=context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is due to using :-

```
    if(!dbExist1)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try
        {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
```

This will result in the database being created as there is a call to `getReadableDatabase`. The database will then be empty (table less).

So change the above to :-

```
    if(!dbExist1)
    {
        try
        {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
```

You will need to delete the App's data or Uninstall the App before running the amended code as the database will exist.

---

The following is something that I put together that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and has been written to understand the functionality of opening databases from the assets (or not if the database exists). As such it does have quite extensive logging and is a little long-winded :-

```
/**
 * Database Helper that includes ability to open database from assets
 * if the database doesn't exist.
 * (i.e. a pre-defined database)
 *
 */

public class OpenAssetDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "OADB-HLPR";
    public static final int MAXIMUM_HELPERS = 10;
    private String mDBPath, mAssetPath;
    private static OpenAssetDBHelper mInstance[] = new OpenAssetDBHelper[MAXIMUM_HELPERS];
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    /**
     * OpenAssetDBHelper Class that will copy a predefined database
     * from the assets folder and then open it is the database;
     *
     * The copy will only be done if the database does not exist.
     *
     * Note this code is intended to be used for development and/or
     * experimentation, hence the extensive logging.
     */

    /**
     * get an OpenAssetDBHelper instance as a singleton;
     * Note! caters for up to 10 OpenAssetDBHelpers for up to 10 databases
     * as specified by the helper_index
     *
     * @param helper_index  Index to this instance/database
     *                      (0-MAXIMUM_HELPERS less 1)
     * @param context       Context for the database
     * @param database      Database name (i.e. file name)
     * @param dbversion     Database version (user_version)
     * @param assetfile     Name of the asset file to be copied to the database
     * @param asset_sub_directories String Array of the sub-directories where
     *                              the asset file is located;
     *                              MUST be in order
     * @return              The resultant OpenAssetDBHelper
     */
    public static synchronized OpenAssetDBHelper getInstance(
            int helper_index,
            Context context,
            String database,
            int dbversion,
            String assetfile,
            String[] asset_sub_directories) {
        // Checck that helper_index is within bounds
        if (helper_index > (MAXIMUM_HELPERS -1)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Helper Index greater than " +
                            MAXIMUM_HELPERS
            );
        }
        if (helper_index < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Helper Index cannot be negative, must be 0-" +
                            MAXIMUM_HELPERS
            );
        }
        // Create the respective OpenAssetDBHelper instance
        if(mInstance[helper_index] == null) {
            mInstance[helper_index] = new OpenAssetDBHelper(context,
                    database,
                    dbversion,
                    assetfile,
                    asset_sub_directories);
        }
        return mInstance[helper_index];
    }

    /**
     * Construct an OpenAssetDBHelper instance;
     * Note! can only be called within class
     *
     * @param context       the context to be used
     * @param database      the database name (equates to filename)
     * @param dbversion     the databaae version (user_version)
     * @param assetfile     The name of the asset file i.e. the pre-defined db
     * @param directories   The hierarchy of directories within the assets folder
     *                      where the asset file is located
     *                      (null or zero elements = in the assets folder)
     */
    private OpenAssetDBHelper(Context context,
                              String database,
                              int dbversion,
                              String assetfile,
                              String[] directories) {
        super(context, database, null, dbversion);
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"OpenAssetDBHelper being constructed.");

        mDBPath = context.getDatabasePath(database).getPath();
        if (assetfile == null || assetfile.length() < 1) {
            assetfile = database;
        }
        mAssetPath = buildAssetPath(directories,assetfile);

        if (!ifDatabaseExists(mDBPath)) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"Database " + database + " not found at " + mDBPath + " so attempting to copy from assets.");
            if (copyDatabaseFromAssets(context,mDBPath, database, mAssetPath)) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Successfully Copied Database from Assets.");
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("No Database Available.");
            }
        }
        // Force Database open and store it
        this.mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        logDatabaseTableInformation(mDB);
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"OpenAssetDBHelper constructed.");
    }


    /**
     * onCreate - This is where you would create tables;
     * Typically this is where you would alter the structure of the database;
     * Note that this is called once for the lifetime of the database.
     * @param db The SQLitedatabase
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " initiated.");
        // As Database is copied from assets nothing to do in onCreate!
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " completed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " initiated.");
        // Nothing to do as it's early days in the Database's lifetime.
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " completed.");
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the Database exists,
     * if it doesn't exists then check to see if
     * the database directory exists,
     * if the directory(ies) does(do) not exist then make the directory(ies);
     *
     *
     * @param dbpath        The path to the database
     * @return              true if the database exists, else false
     */
    private boolean ifDatabaseExists(String dbpath) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " initiated.");
        File db = new File(dbpath);
        if(db.exists()) return true;
        File dir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Copy the Database from the assets folder
     * @param context
     * @param dbpath
     * @return
     */
    private boolean copyDatabaseFromAssets(Context context,String dbpath, String dbname, String asset) {
        String thisclass = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
        Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " initiated");
        InputStream assetsdb;
        OutputStream database;
        File db = new File(dbpath);
        int filesize;
        // Get the asset file
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " attempting to find asset " + asset);
            assetsdb = context.getAssets().open(asset);
            filesize = assetsdb.available();
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " asset " + asset +
                    " located successfully with a size of " +
                    Integer.toString(filesize)
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " Did not locate asset " + asset);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        // Read the first 16 bytes from the asset file
        byte[] dbcheck = new byte[16];
        try {
            assetsdb.read(dbcheck,0,16);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " failed trying to read 16 bytes to check for a valid database. ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        // Check that the asset file is an SQLite database
        String chkdb = new String(dbcheck);
        if(!chkdb.equals("SQLite format 3\u0000")) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " asset " +
                    asset +
                    " is not a valid SQLite Database File (found " +
                    chkdb +
                    " at bytes 1-16 instead of SQLite format 3)");
            try {
                assetsdb.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Not worth doing anything
            }
            return false;
        }
        // Close the asset file
        try {
            assetsdb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass +
                    " failed to close assets file after checking for a valid database."
            );
            return false;
        }
        // Re-open the asset file
        try {
            assetsdb = context.getAssets().open(asset);
            filesize = assetsdb.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass +
                    " failed trying to re-open asset " +
                    asset +
                    " after checking for a valid database."
            );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        // Read the entire asset file into a buffer
        Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass +
                " copying asset database " +
                dbname +
                " into buffer of size " +
                filesize
        );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[filesize];
        // Close the asset file
        try {
            assetsdb.read(buffer);
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass +
                    " closing asset database " + dbname
            );
            assetsdb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass +
                    " failed while copying asset database " +
                    dbname +
                    " (or closing asset database)."
            );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // Open the new database file
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,thisclass + " attempting to open new database file " + dbpath);
            database = new FileOutputStream(dbpath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " failed to open new database file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // Write the new database file
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " writing new database file " + dbpath);
            database.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " failed while writing new database file " + dbpath);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // Flush the new database file
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " flushing new database file " + dbpath);
            database.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " failed while flushing new database file " + dbpath);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // Close the new database file
        try {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " closing new database file " + dbpath);
            database.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, thisclass + " failed while closing new database file " + dbpath);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  false;
        }
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " completed.");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Log Database table Information
     */
    private void logDatabaseTableInformation(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " initiated.");
        String mastertable = "sqlite_master";
        String typecolumn = "type";
        String namecolumn = "name";
        String sqlcolumn = "sql";
        String[] args = new String[]{"table","android_metadata"};
        Cursor csr = db.query(mastertable,
                null,
                typecolumn + "=? AND " + namecolumn + "!=?",
                 args,
                null,null,null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"Database contains Table " +
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(namecolumn)) +
                    " created by SQL " +
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(sqlcolumn))
            );
            logTableInformation(db, csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(namecolumn)));
        }
        csr.close();
        Log.d(LOGTAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " completed.");
    }

    /**
     * Write Table information, Table name, Column Count,
     * Row Count and Column Names to the Log
     * @param table Name of the table to be reported on
     */
    private void logTableInformation(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {
        Cursor csr = db.query(table,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"Table is " +
                table +
                " Column Count = " +
                Integer.toString(csr.getColumnCount()) +
                " Row Count = " +
                Long.toString(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,table))
        );
        StringBuilder columns_as_string = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            columns_as_string.append(s).append(" ");
        }
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "\tColumns are :- " + columns_as_string);
        csr.close();
    }

    /**
     * Build the sub-path to the asset, according to the directories specified
     *
     * @param directories   directories underneath the assets folder where
     *                      the asset files is located, null or empty
     *                      array if file is located directly in the
     *                      assets folder;
     *                      directories must be specified in the order
     *                      in which they appear in the path.
     * @param filename      The filename of the asset
     * @return              The fill sub-path to the asset
     */
    private String buildAssetPath(String[] directories, String filename) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String SEPERATOR = "/";
        if (directories != null && directories.length > 0) {
            for (String s: directories) {
                sb.append(s);
                if (!s.substring(s.length()-1,s.length()).equals(SEPERATOR)) {
                    sb.append(SEPERATOR);
                }
            }
            sb.append(filename);
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return filename;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String DBNAME1 = "openassetdb.db";
    public static final int DB1_INDEX = 0;
    public static final String DBNAME2 = "myshopping";
    public static final int DB2_INDEX = 1;
    public static final String DBNAME3 = "rumplestilskin";
    public static final int DB3_INDEX = 2;

    OpenAssetDBHelper mOADBHlpr;
    OpenAssetDBHelper mShoppingHelper;
    OpenAssetDBHelper mShopper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Example 1 - Database file located in the assets folder and
        //              database name same as file name
        mOADBHlpr = OpenAssetDBHelper.getInstance(DB1_INDEX,
                this,
                DBNAME1,
                DBVERSION,
                DBNAME1,
                null
        );
        // Example 2 - Database file in databases directory of the assets folder
        //              database name different to the asset filename
        mShoppingHelper = OpenAssetDBHelper.getInstance(DB2_INDEX,
                this,
                DBNAME2,
                DBVERSION,
                "shopper",
                new String[]{"databases"}
                );
        // Example 3 - Databse file in databases directory of the assets folder
        //              database name different to the asset filename
        mShopper = OpenAssetDBHelper.getInstance(DB3_INDEX,
                this,
                DBNAME3,
                DBVERSION,
                "Shopper.sqlite",
                new String[]{"databases"}
                );
    }
}
```

This is example output :-

```
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: OpenAssetDBHelper being constructed.
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: ifDatabaseExists initiated.
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database rumplestilskin not found at /data/data/mjt.openassetdb/databases/rumplestilskin so attempting to copy from assets.
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets initiated
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets attempting to find asset databases/Shopper.sqlite
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets asset databases/Shopper.sqlite located successfully with a size of 524288
01-18 00:57:36.582 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets copying asset database rumplestilskin into buffer of size 524288
01-18 00:57:36.586 3276-3276/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 295K, 13% free 6197K/7111K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-18 00:57:36.586 3276-3276/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.892MB for 524300-byte allocation
01-18 00:57:36.602 3276-3278/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 7K, 13% free 6702K/7687K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 13ms
01-18 00:57:36.602 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets closing asset database rumplestilskin
01-18 00:57:36.602 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets attempting to open new database file /data/data/mjt.openassetdb/databases/rumplestilskin
01-18 00:57:36.602 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets writing new database file /data/data/mjt.openassetdb/databases/rumplestilskin
01-18 00:57:36.602 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets flushing new database file /data/data/mjt.openassetdb/databases/rumplestilskin
01-18 00:57:36.606 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets closing new database file /data/data/mjt.openassetdb/databases/rumplestilskin
01-18 00:57:36.606 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: copyDatabaseFromAssets completed.
01-18 00:57:36.606 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Successfully Copied Database from Assets.
01-18 00:57:36.618 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: onCreate initiated.
01-18 00:57:36.618 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: onCreate completed.
01-18 00:57:36.622 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: logDatabaseTableInformation initiated.
01-18 00:57:36.622 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table shops created by SQL CREATE TABLE `shops` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `shopname` TEXT , `shoporder` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 100 , `shopstreet` TEXT , `shopcity` TEXT , `shopstate` TEXT , `shopphone` TEXT , `shopnotes` TEXT )
01-18 00:57:36.622 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is shops Column Count = 8 Row Count = 7
01-18 00:57:36.622 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id shopname shoporder shopstreet shopcity shopstate shopphone shopnotes 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table aisles created by SQL CREATE TABLE `aisles` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `aislename` TEXT , `aisleorder` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 100 , `aisleshopref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL )
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is aisles Column Count = 4 Row Count = 63
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id aislename aisleorder aisleshopref 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table products created by SQL CREATE TABLE `products` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `productname` TEXT , `productorder` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 100 , `productaisleref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `productuses` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `productnotes` TEXT )
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is products Column Count = 6 Row Count = 106
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id productname productorder productaisleref productuses productnotes 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table productusage created by SQL CREATE TABLE `productusage` (`productailseref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `productproductref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `productcost` REAL  DEFAULT 1.00 , `productbuycount` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `productfirstbuydate` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `productlatestbuydate` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `mincost` REAL , `orderinaisle` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 100 , PRIMARY KEY (productailseref, productproductref))
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is productusage Column Count = 8 Row Count = 106
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- productailseref productproductref productcost productbuycount productfirstbuydate productlatestbuydate mincost orderinaisle 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table rules created by SQL CREATE TABLE `rules` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `rulename` TEXT , `ruletype` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `rulepromptflag` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `ruleperiod` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `rulemultiplier` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `ruleactiveon` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `ruleproductref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `ruleaisleref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `ruleuses` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `mincost` REAL  DEFAULT 0 , `maxcost` REAL  DEFAULT 0 , `rulesnumbettoget` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1 )
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is rules Column Count = 13 Row Count = 24
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id rulename ruletype rulepromptflag ruleperiod rulemultiplier ruleactiveon ruleproductref ruleaisleref ruleuses mincost maxcost rulesnumbettoget 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table shoplist created by SQL CREATE TABLE `shoplist` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `slproductid` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `sldateadded` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `slnumbertoget` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1 , `sldone` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `sldategot` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `slcost` REAL  DEFAULT 0 , `productusageref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `aisleref` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL )
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is shoplist Column Count = 9 Row Count = 485
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id slproductid sldateadded slnumbertoget sldone sldategot slcost productusageref aisleref 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Database contains Table appvalues created by SQL CREATE TABLE `appvalues` (`_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY , `valuename` TEXT , `valuetype` TEXT , `valueint` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `valuereal` REAL  DEFAULT '0.0' , `valuetext` TEXT , `valueincludeinsettings` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0 , `valuesettingsinfo` TEXT )
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: Table is appvalues Column Count = 8 Row Count = 7
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR:     Columns are :- _id valuename valuetype valueint valuereal valuetext valueincludeinsettings valuesettingsinfo 
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: logDatabaseTableInformation completed.
01-18 00:57:36.626 3276-3276/? D/OADB-HLPR: OpenAssetDBHelper constructed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick your db file by using any file picker.
This function for replace current database.

> This method working for my room database

```
private void importdb(String db_path) {
        try {
            File file=new File(db_path);
            InputStream mInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            String outFileName = getContext().getDatabasePath(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.db_name)).getAbsolutePath();
          OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = mInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            mOutputStream.flush();
            mOutputStream.close();
            mInputStream.close();
            new CustomMessage(getActivity(), "Database replaced sucessfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomLog.showLogD("WORKING_STOP",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```